# WCF HTTP/SOAP Webservice - Returning exception message in faults

Tags: wcf, custom-errors, soapexception

I have asimple WCF HTTP/SOAP web service, the service implementation looks something like this:

```
public CustomResponse DoSomething(CustomRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        return InternalGubbins.WithErrorHandling.ProcessRequest(request);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Some sort of error occurred that is not gracefully
        // handled elsewhere in the framework
        throw new SoapException("Hmmm, it would seem that the cogs are meshed!", SoapException.ServerFaultCode);
    }
}
```

Now, if that SoapException is thrown I would like the exception message (i.e. `Hmmm, it would seem that the cogs are meshed!`) to be returned to the invoking client without any additional exception detail (i.e. stack traces).

If I set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true (web.config on the server) then the full exception, with stack traces etc, is return to the client.  However if I set it to false, I get a generic message:

> The server was unable to process the
>   request due to an internal error.  For
>   more information about the error,
>   either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either
>   from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from
>   the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to
>   send the exception information back to
>   the client, or turn on tracing as per
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK
>   documentation and inspect the server
>   trace logs.

So the question is, how can I get my SoapException message back to the invoking client? i.e:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:185719f4-6113-4126-b956-7290be375342</a:RelatesTo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
                <s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="en-GB">Hmmm, it would seem that the cogs are meshed!</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to declare a FaultContract on the operation and use FaultException (SoapException is pre WCF). I believe WCF does not send faults back to the client if they are not part of the service contract. I have never tried SoapException but certainly throwing a FaultException has always worked fine for me.

```
[ServiceContract()]    
public interface ISomeService
{
     [OperationContract]
     [FaultContract(typeof(MyFault))]
     CustomResponse DoSomething(CustomRequest request)
}

public class SomeService
{
    public CustomResponse DoSomething(CustomRequest request)
    {
        ...
        throw new FaultException<MyFault>(new MyFault());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly and also answers the next question which was one of using custom detail in the soap exception.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to define a custom exception type then try this

```
try    
{        
    return InternalGubbins.WithErrorHandling.ProcessRequest(request);    
}    
catch    
{
    throw new FaultException("Hmmm, it would seem that the cogs are meshed.");    
}
```

Doing so would send the following response to the client

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Hmmm, it would seem that the cogs are meshed.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, however...  I am using Microsoft Service Trace Viewer to view traces of the service request.  For some reason when using FaultException the trace viewer doesn't work.